# Are the following statements consistent?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, laplacian, potential-theory

I'm currently working on a problem for my PDEs course. The problem states

> Suppose $u(x, y)$ is an electrostatic potential in which $∆u = 0$, defined on the unit disk centered at the origin. Determine if the following statements are consistent or inconsistent. Justify each answer.

- a) $u(x,y) = x^2+y^2+5 $
- b) $u(r=1, θ) = 2 + \sin(θ) $ and $u(r = \frac{1}{2},θ = π) = −1$
- c) $ u(r = 1, θ) = 2 + 4 \sin(θ)$ and $u(r = \frac{1}{2}, θ = π) = \frac{1}{2} $

I simply do not know how to approach this problem.

My attempt at part (a) was
$$ \nabla ^2 u = 4 \neq 0 $$
$$ \therefore \text{not consistent} $$

Is this process correct?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why do you "feel" that is incorrect? Your confusion won't be resolved unless you tell us *why* you think that, not just *that* you think that.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I've edited my post, is that better?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "judging by the values..." What exactly do you mean? How do those values lead you to think the process is incorrect?

Comment: Recall that the Laplacian in polar coordinates is NOT $\Delta u = u_{rr} + u_{\theta\theta}$.  You can derive the new operator in terms of $r$ and $\theta$ by hand.  If you need help see the Wikipedia page, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator.

Comment: For starters, is the function given in a) harmonic?

Comment: Hint: for part (b) you can apply the maximum principle for the Laplacian.